# unable to get value in controller from jquery, ajax in php code igniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_button').click(function () {
        var data = $(this).val();
        //alert(BASE_URL);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            ContentType: 'application/json',
            data: data,
            url: BASE_URL + 'index.php?deo/dashboard',
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occoured!");
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('result from controller');
            }
        });
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function dashboard() {       
    $data = $this->input->post('data');     
    $data = json_decode($data);         
    echo "<script>alert('count ".$data."');</script>";  
}
```

Am trying to send value from my jquery, ajax to controller, am able to get value from my view page to jquery page and able to print that. But unable to send the value from ajax page to controller page, after sending the data i got the success data. but unable to get and print the data in my controller page.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `ContentType` on your client side.

Comment: Already i removed content type and try to send, but the same response only i get. controller not get the value.

Comment: base url of ajax is wrong I think
url: BASE_URL+'index.php?deo/dashboard',         
should be 
url: BASE_URL+'index.php/deo/dashboard',         
OR 
url: BASE_URL+'deo/dashboard',         If url rewrite is enabled

Comment: I tried this too. but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your using firefox a good thing to use is firebug add on and then you can use the console to check for errors on there. To see if the ajax has any errors while sending.

Remove question mark after `index.php?` and I think your base url is not working correct try just.

Url

```
// With index.php

url: 'index.php/deo/dashboard',

// Or without index.php

url: 'deo/dashboard',
```

Or

```
// With index.php

url: <?php echo site_url('index.php/deo/dashboard');?>,

// Or without index.php

url: <?php echo site_url('deo/dashboard');?>,
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_button').click(function () {

        var data = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            url: 'index.php/deo/dashboard',
            // url: <?php echo site_url('index.php/deo/dashboard');?>,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('result from controller');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occoured!");
            }

        });
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function dashboard() {       

    $data = $this->input->post('data');            
    echo "<script>alert('count ".$data."');</script>";  
}
```

Comment: ya, tried this method too. but controller not give any response.

Comment: Did you look on the firebug to see what errors and see what data is beaning posted

Comment: You may need to place a id on you input  or div `var data = $('#data').val();`